# Can Mq4 sensor be used for smoke detection?

Tags: arduino, sensor, gas-sensor

I wanted to ask if Mq4 can be used for fire smoke detection?

I read it have small sensitivity to smoke in the data sheet, but I wanted to know what is the least value in ppm for it to detect smoke ?

MQ-4 datasheet 
http://www.geeetech.com/Documents/MQ-4%20Datasheet.pdf

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have a relevant datasheet?

Comment: I searched on Google , this is a link i founded

Comment: Could you please edit your question to include the link?

Comment: Done, i added wrong text link in the past comment sorry for that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. This sensor is designed to be primarily sensitive to the components of compressed natural gas -- primarily methane. It is not designed as a smoke detector, and will not reliably respond to the presence of smoke or fire.

If you want to detect smoke, use a smoke detector.

Comment: Thanks for your response, i thought since it is written in the data sheet that it have small sensitivity maybe it will be useful, what is the value in ppm you think it will respond to in case of smoke?

Comment: No, that's not a safe assumption to make. That bit in the datasheet is meant as a _warning_ that smoke and/or combustion products may interfere with the part's intended measurements of CNG.

Comment: To be clear, the manufacturer is advertising that they have *minimized* the response to smoke, but it still does have a response.